# finding string between two specified characters in Sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I Have a LinkedIn Link in my database Column here i have to check with my linkedIn ID where the linked in link is inserted two or more times.
ex:https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=246925795&authType=name&authToken=sygl&trk=prof-sb-browse_map-name

i have to check with id in database
if id repeats two or more times it must be deleted and only one must be left.
id=246925795

Please Someone Help me

Comment: can you elaborate with some sample data..if the record inserted another it need to be deleted or with in the string have same number two times it need to be deleted..can you explain???

Comment: within the string having id 2 times i have inserted without my knowledge two or more times only linked id is same

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH Ids AS (
    SELECT Id,
           SUBSTRING(LinkedInLink, IdStart, IdEnd - IdStart) AS LinkedInId
    FROM table
         CROSS APPLY (
             SELECT CHARINDEX('id=', LinkedInLink) AS IdStart
         ) AS CA1
         CROSS APPLY (
             SELECT CHARINDEX('&', LinkedInLink, IdStart) AS IdEnd
         ) AS CA2
)
,Duplicates AS (
    SELECT LinkedInId
          ,MAX(id) AS LastDuplicateId
    FROM Ids
    GROUP BY LinkedInId
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
DELETE FROM Table
WHERE Id IN (SELECT LastDuplicateId FROM Duplicates)
```

Comment: If the count is 5 it is deleting only one record, i have to delete all the other records except the first one

Comment: In Online Sql Server error occurs as Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: @Ravindran, regarding deleting only one record. Run it several times until `0 rows affected`. Regarding error. You need to filter out rows which does not include a valid link.

Comment: K Bro, In Online Sql Server error occurs as Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: WITH Ids AS (
    SELECT id,
           SUBSTRING(links, IdStart, IdEnd - IdStart) AS LinkedInId
    FROM addedlinks
         CROSS APPLY (
             SELECT CHARINDEX('id=', links) AS IdStart
         ) AS CA1
         CROSS APPLY (
             SELECT CHARINDEX('&authType', links, IdStart) AS IdEnd
         ) AS CA2
)
,Duplicates AS (
    SELECT LinkedInId
          ,MAX(id) AS LastDuplicateId
    FROM Ids
    GROUP BY LinkedInId
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
DELETE FROM addedlinks
WHERE Id IN (SELECT LastDuplicateId FROM Duplicates)

Comment: In The above Code i have changed it is working in Localhost but in online server it giving error message as Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Answer (score 0):

It will be best if you use Regular Expression to do such search opertaion.
You can create a Utility class that will perform search + replace in C# or VB.Net and then import that class(DLL) in the SQl Server. In your SQL query you can use it as a function.

Refer : [Link](http://www.tryexcept.com/articles/2009/09/22/using-net-assemblies-inside-sql-server-quick-start-guide.html)

Comment: Can u give me a sample, i have no idea can u explain me more with thanks for the help